# mount -t cifs + mount error(13): Permission denied

Tags: linux, windows, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, cifs

we have windows server with IP address - `98.12.23.34` and with folder `max_stage`

from windows browser its looks like:

```
   This PC > max_stage(K)
```

and we want to mount the WIN folder `max_stage` to `/mnt/target`  on our Linux server - RHEL 7.6 server.

we installed already the cifs rpm

```
rpm -qa | grep cifs
cifs-utils-6.2-7.el7.x86_64
```

and we did the follwing:

```
 mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0 -v //98.12.23.34/max_stage  /mnt/target -o username=papa,pass='japeto'
```

and we get the following exeption:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=98.12.23.34,unc=\\98.12.23.34\max_stage,vers=2.0,user=papa,passs,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied   <-------------
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

how to know why we get the exception about `Permission denied (13)`, and what is the additional configuration that we need to do from our side ?

or

how to check on WIN machine the user/pass as papa/japeto that are correct?

Reference - https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-mount-cifs

Comment: Does `-o sec=ntlmssp` work? Can you ask your server administrator 1) whether they require Kerberos or not, and/or 2) whether the server has "Microsoft network server: Server SPN target name validation level" GPO enabled or not?

Comment: I think this is new WIN machine and user/pass not set , so can you help me to understand how to configure the user/pass ? for mount access ?

Comment: Well, can you actually log in to Windows with that username and password? Is the username listed in lusrmgr.msc? (Is there Active Directory involved?) There is no user database "for mount access" specifically, either the OS has a user named 'papa' or it doesn't.

Comment: Compare with this [RHEL article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263) where the mount command is written differently.

Comment: yes I can login and in run I type lusrmgr.msc , and this open window with "localusers and group "

Comment: Are you running the `mount` command with `root` permissions?

Comment: yes I am running with root